# Use same fragment multiple times in navigation graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I want to migrate my project to use navigation components.
In my Activity there is a bottom navigation, which navigates through different instances of the same Fragment (with different arguments).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0Cs2MQxyIs) explained about bottomNavigation support.
But is it possible to reuse same Fragment in the same navigation graph, with different IDs and params?

I can't find way in google documentations.

Comment: are you using `NavigationUI` with `BottomNavigationView`?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to define your nav_graph with multiple destinations and reuse the same fragment. Something like this,

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
  app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_tab1">

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/navigation_tab1"
      android:name="com.myapp.MyFragment"
      android:label="Tab1">

      <action
          android:id="@+id/action_goto_page1"
          app:destination="@id/navigation_page1" />
      <argument
          android:name="tab1_arg1"
          android:defaultValue="Default"
          app:argType="string" />
  </fragment>

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/navigation_tab2"
      android:name="com.myapp.MyFragment"
      android:label="Tab2">

      <action
          android:id="@+id/action_goto_page2"
          app:destination="@id/navigation_page2" />
      <argument
          android:name="tab2_arg1"
          android:defaultValue="Default"
          app:argType="string" />
  </fragment>

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/navigation_tab3"
      android:name="com.myapp.MyFragment"
      android:label="Tab3">

      <action
          android:id="@+id/action_goto_page3"
          app:destination="@id/navigation_page3" />
      <argument
          android:name="tab3_arg1"
          android:defaultValue="Default"
          app:argType="string" />
  </fragment>
</navigation>
```

However, it's best to refactor your code to have multiple Fragments (each doing one thing) for better maintenance and clean code.